# How to choose correct DBSet to query during runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

For database I have an SQL database which I access by using Entity Framework (6) DBContext. The database has two tables, `CarTable` and `BicycleTable` and both tables have colum `id`.

As for CSharp objects, I have an interface `Vechile` which has one attribute `string id`. Two classes implement the interface, `Car`and `Bicycle`.

I am using a function which takes `Vechile`-object as an argument.

```
public class TestClass {
    SqlTestContext context = new SqlTestContext("connection string");

    public Vechile returnExistingFromDatabase(Vechile vechileObject) {
        // how I can query correct DBSet/Table using vechileObject.id?
    }        
}
```

I have tried multiple approaches but no luck.
I have tried to set the correct `DBSet`via type. Essentially `context.(typeof(Car)).Single.....`
I have also tried to create an abstract method that would return the `DBSet` to be queried:

```
public DBSet<Vechile> returnDbSet(){
    return context.Car; // can not use the `Vechile`-interface for this
}
```

I could use if-else-block but it would break open-close-principle in my project so I would prefer something more maintainable.

Comment: Look into LINQ. Basically await context.Car.Where(w => w.VehicleId == vechileObject).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: @GHDevOps I can get the object from the database if I manually set the table. My problem is about setting the correct DBSet on runtime. So in your code snipped the `Car` part would need to be determined runtime since it the same function should be able to get object from either `Car` or `Bicycle` table.

Comment: Use generics: return context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();. Then you can call it like await returnDbSet<Car>().Where(w => w.VehicleId == vechileObject.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: Note your context will have to be scoped and not transient if you return an IQueryable.